# Working with quicksort

Tags: java, quicksort, pseudocode

I am working on a quicksort from my data structures and algorithms book. In the book it lists a quicksort method then a hoare partition that it wants you to use with the quick sort. I seem to be having an issue where my hoare partition is using out of bounds numbers on the array. Either it uses 8 or if I try to fix that it goes to -1. Am I converting the books pseudo correctly into java?

Quicksort pseudo code

```
QuickSort(A, p, r)
if p<r
    q = partition(A, p, r);
    QuickSort(A, p, q - 1);
    QuickSort(A, q, r);
```

Hoare-Partition Pseudo Code

```
Hoare-Partition(A,p,r)
    x= A[p]
    i = p-1
    j=r+1
    while true
        repeat
            j=j-1
        until A [j] <= x
        repeat
            i = i +1
        until A[i] >= x
        if i < l
           exchange A[i] with A[j]
        else return j
```

My code

```
public class RunSort {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] sortNumbers = {4,5,6,2,3,7,2,1};
        int[] sorted = new int[sortNumbers.length];

        sorted = QuickSort(sortNumbers, 1, sortNumbers.length);
        System.out.print(sorted);
    }

    public static int[] QuickSort(int[] A, int p, int r){
        if(p < r){
            int q = partition(A, p, r);
            QuickSort(A, p, q - 1);
            QuickSort(A, q, r);
        }
        return A;

    }

    public static int partition(int[] A, int p, int r){
        int x = A[p];
        int i = p - 1;
        int j = r + 1;
        int temp;

        while(true){
            while(A[j] <= x && j != 0){
                j--;
            }
            while(A[i] >= x && i != A.length){
                i++;
            }
            if(i < j){
                temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[j];
                A[j] = temp;
            }else{
                return j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: `repeat {...} until (condition)` does not do the same thing as `while (condition) {...}`.

Comment: Oh I see where I went wrong. I am testing it while it is that condition not until.

Comment: Would changing it to this be correct
while(A[j] > x){
    j--;
   }
   while(A[i] < x){
    i++;
   }

Comment: I think `do { ... } while (!condition)` would be closer to what you want.  `while (condition) { ... }` evaluates the condition *before* performing the block, which is really not the same as what the `repeat` pseudocode is describing.

Comment: @shinjuo Not quite: `while(){}` checks the condition before executing the code block, `repeat{}until()` checks it after executing the code block.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the text, pseudocode often uses 1..arrayLength as the index bounds on an array, but in Java, et al., it's 0..arrayLength-1.  You'll need to adjust the arguments to the main `QuickSort` call in `main`.

(As a nitpick, `QuickSort` should start with a lowercase letter by convention.)